# PostGIS ST_DWithin negative distance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, select-by-location

I am trying to replicate an ArcGIS select by location type query in PosGIS.
In ArcGIS I am using the "are within a distance of the source layer feaure" where the target layer is municipalities and the source layer is a 'zone'. I am applying a negative distance to only select the municipalities that are 50 feet deep in the 'zone'. I am doing this query as opposed to the boolean intersect method because I do not want any municipalites that simply touch a boundary of the 'zone'. It works good in ArcGIS. In PostGIS I am trying to use this expression

```
where ST_DWithin('zone'.geom,mun.geom,-50)
```

but it gives me this error

```
ERROR:  Tolerance cannot be less than zero

********** Error **********

ERROR: Tolerance cannot be less than zero
SQL state: XX000
```

in ArcGIS

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any tables/test data, it's hard to test this however, [`ST_Buffer`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) has a note on it that you may find applicable,

> Negative radii: For polygons, a negative radius can be used, which will shrink the polygon rather than expanding it.

So I would think you could

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  ST_BUFFER( zone.geom, -50 )
  mun.geom,
  0
)
```

Comment: Good answer, you could also use ST_Contains, which is the inverse of ST_Within, ie, zone and mun in the opposite order, seeing as the tolerance no longer matters. I have no idea if there would be any performance implications either way.

Comment: yeah that worked perfectly

Comment: @JohnBarça in terms of performance my original query took about 20 second to run while the new took about 1:40

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like this will work, but with performance penalties:

```
WHERE ST_Contains(
  ST_Buffer(zone.geom, -50)
  mun.geom
)
```

The trouble is you're doing an unindexed join (you don't have a spatial index on the negative buffer of the zone) and you're also applying the buffer to every candidate pairing of the full join as a result. You want to combine an indexed filter that is a superset of the exact filter, something like:

```
WHERE ST_Contains(
  zone.geom,
  mun.geom
)
AND ST_Contains(
  ST_Buffer(zone.geom, -50)
  mun.geom
)
```

Now you get the index working for you (via the first contains) and also an optimized contains test (so only pairings that are already contained at 0m buffer come through) before you run the negative buffer and final test. You'll still be running negative buffers, but hopefully many fewer, so you'll get a faster result.

Comment: Depending on how often he does it, he could also create a GIST INDEX on `ST_Buffer(zone.geom, -50)`.

Comment: Or even better, just add a geometry column with the smallified shapes.